# How to custom format like ###,##,##,### for numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I am looking for a custom format code to make the numbers like 100,00,00,000 (This is like a combination of Indian and American currency format).  I need every number in this format and all zeros must be "-". I searched everywhere and found one useful post by Gary's Student but I could not adjust the same to my need.

[Gary's Student's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/928536/how-do-you-format-numbers-in-excel-for-indian-currency-rupees/928597#928597)

Comment: Even leading zeros should be dashes??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to process the data numerically, you can create the equivalent text string with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,3) & "," & MID(A1,4,2) & "," &  MID(A1,6,2) & "," & RIGHT(A1,3),"0","-")
```

[image]